# Medical test for travel to Canada

Tags: canada, student-visa, indian-citizens, medical

I am an Indian citizen. I have a Canadian student visa valid from April 2016 to March 2018. I am planning to travel to Canada in early 2017. The validity of my medical test performed for the issuance of the said visa is until December 2016 (as it was done in December 2015).

Will I be able to travel to Canada to enter as a student in early 2017 without having to undergo the medical test again?

Comment: Who (else) says the validity of the medical test is one year (for these purposes)?

Comment: As per the CIC website "Your medical exam results are valid for 12 months only. If you do not come to Canada as a visitor, student or worker within that time, you may need to have another exam."

Comment: Are you sure? Will I be allowed to enter Canada after the validity of the medical exam is over given I have a valid visa with me?

Comment: Are you still going as a student?  Did you already travel on this student visa? This question most likely ought to be on [expatriates.SE].

Comment: Yes I will be going as a student. This will be my first trip to Canada.

Answer (score 1):

At the time you plan to enter Canada, it will be more than a year since you were tested, as required for the issuance of your visa.
[Government of Canada Immigration](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/medical/medexams-temp.asp) notes that (added emphasis mine):

> Your medical exam results are **valid for 12 months only.** If you do not come to Canada as a visitor, student or worker within that time, you may need to have another exam.

Consequently, it will not be valid when you attempt to enter Canada, and you might not be admitted. Prior to travel, it would be best to verify whether you need to have a repeat test.